QGIS Expand rule-based symbology with multiple levels using python
Using Python, I want to expand a rule-based symbology with multiple rule-levels in the table of contents.
I tried using the following code, but it expands only the first rule, but not the subsequent ones:
LayerNode = root.findLayer(layer.id())
LayerNode.setExpanded(True)

How do I expand the subsequent rules/categories?

Since QgsLayerTreeView extends Qt's QTreeView class, it inherits it's methods. In particular we can use QTreeView.expandRecursively() to which you need to pass the QModelIndex belonging to the layer's parent legend node.
layer = QgsProject.instance().mapLayersByName('Your_layer_name')[0]
layer_tree_view = iface.layerTreeView()
layer_tree_model = layer_tree_view.layerTreeModel()
root = layer_tree_model.rootGroup()
layer_tree_layer = root.findLayer(layer.id())
layer_index = layer_tree_view.node2index(layer_tree_layer)# Returns a QModelIndex *Since 3.18
layer_tree_view.expandRecursively(layer_index)

